# Going from Windows XP to Windows 8.1

Tags: windows, windows-xp, windows-8, windows-8.1

I have been watching videos on how it is done by Microsoft but they all talk about and use MDT/WDS/SCCM.

Is there a way to transfer everything over without using those enterprise options? Or am I better off just transferring files off 1 by 1 and re-installing software?

I have 2 new machines and I want to move everything off from the Windows XP machines.

Answer (score 1):

The Windows 8.1 disk won't allow you to migrate directly from Windows XP. In this case, you have to back up your files ([as stated in this Microsoft article](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/upgrade-from-windows-vista-xp-tutorial)) and then upgrade.